# Azure-integration in Visual Studio broken

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

Since this morning (Central European Time) my Azure integration in Visual Studio 2013 (Premium) has been broken.

When "Managing subscriptions", I now get the following error:

[image]

```
Unable to retrieve Web Apps from some subscriptions:

Subscription Microsoft Azure Enterprise: The remote server returned an 
error: (403) Forbidden. The HTTP request was forbidden with client 
authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
```

And when I log in now, I get this error:

[image]

```
An error ocurred during the sign in process:
multiple_matching_tokens_detected: The cache contains multiple tokens 
satisfying the requirements. Call AcquireToken again providing more 
requirements (e.g. UserId)
```

Bonus info:

The email address for my Microsoft Account for my MSDN Subscription is the same as the email address for my O365-account, and when I now try to log into Azure thru Visual Studio, I am asked to federate against my company's O365 thing.

It has worked perfectly before - and latest last night.

Anyone know what has happened?

Comment: Has someone switched your Visual Studio Online instance over to use Organisational Ids or removed your Microsoft Account (formerly Live ID) from the VSO tenant? What happens when you open VSO in a web browser? Is your Azure Subscription functional and the account paid?

Comment: VSO is not in play here. IT's just Visual Studio -> Azure. My MSDN/Azure subscription is active, functional and paid.

Comment: And just to be clear - I use "Server explorer"-window in Visual Studio to access Azure

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error (the first one) today. I just switched from trial period to paid subscription. That might be the reason.
I've got rid of this error after signing off from Visual Studio and signing in again.

Although I haven't had the second one, it does say something about 'Cache containing multiple tokens'. Sounds like you've got multiple subscriptions too. Maybe clearing the cache somehow works?